# auth0-react and keeping a user logged in on reload

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I'm using `@auth0/auth0-react` and am having some difficulty in understanding the best way to keep a user logged in.

`useAuth0` works, but if I refresh the page, it seemingly needs to re-authenticate which takes a couple seconds. So if you're logged in, and refresh the page, you'll briefly see unauthenticated content before the authenticated stuff loads in.

The page itself is available to both authenticated and unauthenticated users, I'm only using auth0 to limit some features available on the page. So locking the route down unless it's authenticated isn't an option for me.

I know I can check `loading`, but feels like that should only be used for the first login, not for page reloads.

Figured auth0 would store a cookie or something, which shouldn't take that long to load.

Provider

```
export const Auth0Wrapper = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<any>): JSX.Element | null => {
    const { domain, clientId, audience } = useEnv();

    const onRedirectCallback = (appState: AppState | undefined) => {
        navigate(appState?.returnTo || '/', { replace: true });
    };

    if (!(domain && clientId && audience)) {
        return null;
    }
    return (
        <Auth0Provider
            domain={domain}
            clientId={clientId}
            audience={audience}
            redirectUri={location.origin}
            onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
        >
            {children}
        </Auth0Provider>
    );
};
```

My component

```
export const AuthenticationButton = () => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

    return isAuthenticated ? <LogoutButton /> : <LoginButton />;
};
```